# How to configure multiple custom queries in Single Kafka Connector property file

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Currently i have configured single query in Kafka JDBC source connector property file and this runs in standalone mode. How do i configure multiple queries in single property file with a different name assigned to each query and store it under single topics.

Is this feasible or i need to build multiple property file for each query with same topic name and add those property filename in the execution script separated by comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one query per connector properties

If you ran Connect in Distributed mode, you'd post individual configurations to the running REST API, still only one query per connector.

For example

```
connect-distributed connect-distributed.properties 
curl -X POST localhost:8083/connectors -d@config1.json
curl -X POST localhost:8083/connectors -d@config2.json
```

Otherwise, Standalone mode takes space separated property files, not comma separated

Comment: Thanks for the response, I would like to run the connectors in distributed mode, in that case how can i configure the SQL queries. Should i need to run the same property file in all the  connectors like Logstash JDBC input plugin. Can you pleas help me on this

Comment: It's still separate configurations, just JSON instead of property files. Same exact key-value pairs

Comment: You mean when i run connectors in distributed mode, i need to make rest api call with the connection and query details in json format. Why cannt i start the workers separately with property file in each machine. Can you please explain  bit on this

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You can't start distributed mode with connectors. You just start it with the worker configuration file. To add connectors, you use the API. To create a cluster, you would run the connect-distributed command again with the `group.id` property matching the other workers, and they all share the same connector configurations and you can use the API from any instance. Distributed mode is scalable and fault-tolerant, that's the main reason to use it over standalone

Comment: Hi Thanks..now i understood. In distributed mode, workers are started separately not along with connector configuration files. Today i created two workers, can you please tell me whether both workers should run on same or different port, both the workers below to same group-id. How workers handles the clustering here, because i creating the connector by hiiting the REST API http://localhost:8083/connectors, how this connector will be managed by two workers

Comment: Same port is easiest for administration purposes. Some people put http load balancers in front of the API of all workers.

Comment: Hi Thanks..now i understood. In distributed mode, workers are started separately not along with connector configuration files. Today i created two workers,  both the workers are running at port 8083 and 8084 and both the workers below to same group-id. How workers handles the clustering here, i am creating a connector by hitting http://localhost:8083/connector, how both the workers handles this, which worker will fetch the DB events. I am not clear on this concept. Can you please help me on this

Comment: Sorry i edited my comment, can you please tell me, whether i can ran two worker process at same port. If one worker goes down another worker can still get the DB events

Comment: That's too broad to really answer in a comment, and I personally don't even know other than Kafka Connect has its own internal protocols for delegating configurations and starting worker tasks/threads. There's already a question asking how it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026235/kafka-connect-internals-how-connectors-and-tasks-got-deployed-around-the-conne